# Using dplyr in order to fill a new df with the content of one df with conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Hel lo I would need help in order to create a nex df from this one :

```
      Groups                   COL1  COL2     COL3  COL4  COL5
0     G1      DJJE):Canis_lupus  ABFC  Canidae     4     3
1     G1      JUUI):Canis_canis    YH  Canidae    10    12
2     G1        KI):Lupus_lupus    ZA  canidae     2    12
3     G2  IOZ):Felis_sylvestris    OP  Falidae     0     2
4     G2        KI):Felis_felis    UI  Falidae     6     8
5     G3        YY):Canis_lupus    ER  Raninae     7     9
6     G3        SD):Canis_lupus    GH  Raninae     2     3
7     G3        DZ:)Lupus_lupus    EZ  Raninae     6     8
8     G4           KUU):O_outan    LO  Babounae    4     8
9     G4   OK:)Felis_sylvestris    IO  Babounae    4     8
9     G4   LK:)Felis_sylvestris    IU  Babounae    8     9
```

The idea is for each `Groups` to create a df wth a column `COL3`  as first column and then fill it by adding new column and letters.

Here is an exemple :

`G1` is composed of `3 different Names` (after the `:)` pattern) :
 - `Canis_lupus` 
 - `Canis_canis` 
 - `Lupus_lupus`

then if `COL4` and `COL5` of the values are both `> 5` I assign the value `A` in the new df 
and if `COL4` and `COL5 < 5` then I assign the value `B` in the new df

ex `DJJE):Canis_lupus` have both `COL4 and COL5 < 5` then `Canis_lupus` in `Canidae` will have a `B` value.

ex  `YY):Canis_lupus` in `G3 h`ave `COL4 and COL5 > 5` then `Canis_lupus` in the `Raninae` will have a `A` value

if there is a case where there is both `COL4 and COL5 > 5` and `COL4 and COL5 < 5` as for exemple :

`row5` and `row6` for `Canis_lupus` in `Raninae`, then A > B so I give the letter A.

if `COL4 > 5` and `COL5 < 5` then I give the letter `B`

if `COL4 < 5` and `COL5 > 5` then I give the letter `B`
here is the expected output :

```
COL3     Canis_lupus Canis_canis Lupus_lupus Felis_sylvestris O_outan 
Canidae  B           A           A           NA               NA   
Falidae  A           NA          NA          B                A    
Raninae  A           NA          A           NA               NA  
Babounae NA          NA          NA          A                B
```

and here are the data :

```
structure(list(Groups = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("G1", "G2", "G3", "G4"), class = "factor"), 
    COL1 = structure(c(1L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 11L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 
    9L, 8L), .Label = c("DJJE):Canis_lupus", "DZ:)Lupus_lupus", 
    "IOZ):Felis_sylvestris", "JUUI):Canis_canis", "KI):Felis_felis", 
    "KI):Lupus_lupus", "KUU):O_outan", "LK:)Felis_sylvestris", 
    "OK:)Felis_sylvestris", "SD):Canis_lupus", "YY):Canis_lupus"
    ), class = "factor"), COL2 = structure(c(1L, 10L, 11L, 8L, 
    9L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("ABFC", "ER", "EZ", 
    "GH", "IO", "IU", "LO", "OP", "UI", "YH", "ZA"), class = "factor"), 
    COL3 = structure(c(3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), .Label = c("Babounae", "canidae", "Canidae", "Falidae", 
    "Raninae"), class = "factor"), COL4 = c(4L, 10L, 2L, 0L, 
    6L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 8L), COL5 = c(3L, 12L, 12L, 2L, 8L, 
    9L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

does someone have an idea ?

maybe an idea would be to use :

```
case_when(
      any(COL4>=5 & COL5>= 5) ~ "A",
      any(COL4<5 & COL5>= 5) ~ "B",
      any(COL4>=5 & COL5< 5) ~ "B",
      any(COL4<5 & COL5< 5) ~ "B"
```

and then a `pivot_wider()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `tiyverse` (`tidyr`, `stringr` and `dplyr`) on your dataset named `df`:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(value = case_when(COL4>=5 & COL5>= 5 ~ "A",
                           COL4<5  & COL5>= 5 ~ "B",
                           COL4>=5 & COL5< 5  ~ "B",
                           COL4<5  & COL5< 5  ~ "B"),
         COL1 = str_extract(df$COL1, "(?<=\\):|:\\)).*"),
         COL3 = str_to_title(as.character(COL3))) %>%
  select(-c(Groups, COL2, COL4, COL5)) %>%
  group_by(COL3, COL1) %>% 
  arrange(value, .by_group=TRUE) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "COL1", values_from="value")
```

This gives:

```r
# A tibble: 4 x 7
# Groups:   COL3 [4]
  COL3     Felis_sylvestris O_outan Canis_canis Canis_lupus Lupus_lupus Felis_felis
  <chr>    <chr>            <chr>   <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr>      
1 Babounae A                B       NA          NA          NA          NA         
2 Canidae  NA               NA      A           B           B           NA         
3 Falidae  B                NA      NA          NA          NA          A          
4 Raninae  NA               NA      NA          A           A           NA
```

Annotations:

- I separated `COL1` by `):` and `:)` since both occured.
- The solution seems a little bit complicated. I bet there are easier approaches.